# Fetching all keys and values from a hash at once in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

In **Ruby, I want to **fetch** all keys and values at once without needing to iterate through the hash.

The keys are variables and the values of data type boolean.

In the **new Example**, the only parameters, which are exchangeable, are `var1 => true` and `var2 => true`.
So, I want that the hash keys are treated as keywords.

**New Example:**

```
var1 = "Attr1"
var2 = "Attr2"
var3 = "Attr2"

hash = {var1 => true, var2 => true}

def method(h = {})

    puts("Works")

end


method(hash, var3 => true) #Error
```

**Old Example:**

```
hash = {var1 => true, var2 => false}
self.some_method_i_cant_change_1(var1 => true, var2 => false, var3 => true)
self.some_method_i_cant_change_2(var1 => true, var2 => false, var3 => true)
... n methods
self.some_method_i_cant_change_n(var1 => true, var2 => false, var3 => true)
```

It's not possible to pass the hash to that method directly.

So, `self.some_method_i_cant_change(hash, var3 => true)` isn't allowed

Comment: there is a double splat, so hash keys are treated as keywords: `self.some_method_i_cant_change(**hash)`

Comment: `foo(var1 => true, var2 => false)` is equivalent to `foo({var1 => true, var2 => false})` or `foo(hash)` with `hash = {var1 => true, var2 => false}`. Can you double check how the method is called?

Comment: @Stefan If there are predefined values, it doesn't work. I will edit my post to make it more clear. Example: `a={"h" =>1, "b" => 2}` `def method(option={})` `method("z"=>1,a)` results in an error. And `method("z"=>1,**a)` does work

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't understand your question and could really use a minimal reproducible example. I don't understand how the `some_method_i_cant_change_*` methods are intended to use their arguments.

Comment: Can you show the method signatures? How are they defined and what arguments do they take?

Comment: I've updated the whole topic to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand the issue, but as I understand you need to call some method and pass single argument as hash using few existing hashes

```rb
var1 = "Attr1"
var2 = "Attr2"
var3 = "Attr3"

hsh = { var1 => true, var2 => true }

def some_method(hsh = {})
  p hsh
end
```

```rb
# With hashes merge
some_method(hsh.merge(var3 => true))

# Using double splat
some_method(var3 => true, **hsh)

# With mutation of original hash
hsh[var3] = true
some_method(hsh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
hash = {var1 => true, var2 => false}
self.some_method_i_cant_change(*(hash.map { |k, v| {k =>  v} }))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
Unfortunately, i need to handle several methods, so I guess it's a good solution for one method but not for several methods.
I will edit my post to be more clear, thank you